# Which Membership Plugin?

Tags: plugins, membership

I’m in the pre-production phase of a site I’m building. It’s a for a professional group. The functionality I want is just a profile. There’s no e-commerce or limited access needed. The People page on Creative Mornings is exactly what I have in mind: https://creativemornings.com/people

I’ve been looking at membership plugins and I’ve worked with BuddyPress in the past and what I’ve seen is overly complicated. Does anyone know of a membership plugin (or other solution) for this?

To be clear code doesn’t scare me, but I’m not a developer, so I’d prefer to have a solution that is mostly off the shelf, but am willing to do some customization to make the last 10% perfect.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "they" like plugin recommendations here. Have you tried searching the [WP Plugin Repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=membership) and reading the reviews and descriptions. There's some great simple ones out there.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [Our Team By WooThemes](https://vi.wordpress.org/plugins/our-team-by-woothemes/screenshots/)

Don't try to search "membership plugin," use keyword "Our Team" instead.

Btw, you should not ask for plugin suggests in here. It's out of scope.

Comment: "you should not ask for plugin suggests in here". 

It seems inappropriate then for you to tell Brian to ignore my suggestion to search the repository and instead recommend Brian to use a specific plugin.

Comment: He should no. But he did. And we here to make the community better. Just suggest him, then notify him not do it again.